# how to fix Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'translate' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i can't find solution for this bug
i wrok on site web multi language but i can't don't know how to fix this bug

```
class translate{
constructor(){

    document.getElementById("fr").addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        this.translate("fr");
    });
    document.getElementById("en").addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        this.translate("en");
    });
    this.translate(localStorage.getItem("language"));
}
translate(language){
    if(language == "fr"){
        document.getElementById("myAnchor").href = "http://www.cnn.com/";
    }
    else if (language =="en"){
        document.getElementById("myAnchor").href = "http://www.google.com/";  
    }
    localStorage.setItem("language",language);
}
}
onload = new translate();
```

[image: this bug]

code Html and link i need to change

```
    <div class="contenu-space-two"> 
     <div class="row mx-0">
             <div class=" col-2">
                     <img src="./resources/_images/shopping-cart.png" class="logo-link" alt="">
             </div>
             <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-8" > 
                     <h4 class="lang" key="boutiques">Boutiques</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="col-2">
                      <a id="myAnchor" href="#"><img src="./resources/_images/arrow-link.png" class="arrow-link" alt=""></a>
             </div>
             <hr class="line_link">
    </div>
```

and this code language

```
                <div id="langContainer">
                <a class="translate" id="lang_link[en]" href="#" style="display:none"><img src="./resources/_images/flags/en.png?1595436503" title="English"></a>
                <a class="translate" id="lang_link[fr]" href="#" style="display:none"><img src="./resources/_images/flags/fr.png?1595436503" title="Fran&ccedil;ais"></a>
            </div>
```

Comment: looks like `translate` has already been declared. choose a different name for your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This variable has probably already been declared.
Check this js file and the others the page references.

If there are many you can try to change the name of this class.